# Java Regex ReplaceAll with grouping

Tags: java, regex

I want to surround all tokens in a text with tags in the following manner:

Input: `" abc fg      asd "`

Output:`" <token>abc</token> <token>fg</token>      <token>asd</token> "`

This is the code I tried so far:

```
String regex = "(\\s)([a-zA-Z]+)(\\s)";
String text = " abc fg      asd ";
text = text.replaceAll(regex, "$1<token>$2</token>$3");
System.out.println(text);
```

Output:`" <token>abc</token> fg      <token>asd</token> "`

Note: for simplicity we can assume that the input starts and ends with whitespaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
String regex = "(?<=\\s)([a-zA-Z]+)(?=\\s)";
...
text = text.replaceAll(regex, "<token>$1</token>");
```

Comment: And `text = text.replaceAll(regex, "<token>$1</token>");` In fact why not `text = text.replaceAll("\\w+", "<token>$0</token>");`?

Answer (score 0):

If your tokens are only defined with a character class you don't need to describe what characters are around. So this should suffice since the regex engine walks from left to right and since the quantifier is greedy:

```
String regex = "[a-zA-Z]+";
text = text.replaceAll(regex, "<token>$0</token>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                                 // meaning not a space, 1+ times
String result = input.replaceAll("([^\\s]+)", "<token>$1</token>");
```

this matches everything that isn't a space. Prolly the best fit for what you need. Also it's greedy meaning it will never leave out a character that it shouldn't ( it will never find the string "as" in the string "asd" when there is another character with which it matches)

Comment: `\\S`==`[^\\s]`. Also you don't need to wrap entire regex with parenthesis to create group matching entire regex because group 0 already does it for you. So try `replaceAll("\\S+", "<token>$0</token>");`